# Условие if в сортировке order by mysql

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть таблица:

```
id|user_with|user_creator|fav_user_with|fav_user_creator|
1 |   10    |     15     |      1      |        0       |
2 |   10    |     15     |      0      |        1       |
3 |   15    |     10     |      0      |        1       |
4 |   15    |     10     |      1      |        0       |
5 |   15    |     10     |      0      |        1       |
```

Как я могу сделать сортировку.

Если `user_creator = 15` и `fav_user_creator = 1` то `order by fav_user_creator desc, id desc`.

Если `user_with = 15` и `fav_user_with = 1` то `order by fav_user_with desc, id desc`.

Должно получиться при первом условии:

```
id|user_with|user_creator|fav_user_with|fav_user_creator|
2 |   10    |     15     |      0      |        1       |
5 |   15    |     10     |      0      |        1       |
4 |   15    |     10     |      1      |        0       |
3 |   15    |     10     |      0      |        1       |
1 |   10    |     15     |      1      |        0       |
```

Должно получиться при втором условии:

```
id|user_with|user_creator|fav_user_with|fav_user_creator|
4 |   15    |     10     |      1      |        0       |
5 |   15    |     10     |      0      |        1       |
3 |   15    |     10     |      0      |        1       |
2 |   10    |     15     |      1      |        0       |
1 |   10    |     15     |      0      |        1       |
```

Comment: А как эти два условия пересекаются между собой, если в одной выборке есть записи и по одному условию и по другому, то как они должны быть относительно друг друга

Comment: *Если ... то ...* Условие некорректно. "Если" - применяется к одной записи, тогда как "то" - ко всему набору. Условие сортировки должно определять относительный порядок двух записей в зависимости от значений в обеих записях.

Comment: *Должно получиться при первом условии* не соответствует `order by fav_user_creator desc, id desc`. То же - для второго условия и результата.

Comment: «Если fav_user_creator = 1 то order by fav_user_creator» - какой вообще смысл сортировать по константе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
…
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN user_creator = 15 AND fav_user_creator = 1 THEN fav_user_creator
    WHEN user_with = 15 AND fav_user_with = 1 THEN fav_user_with 
  END desc,
  id desc
```

Comment: возможно это то что и ожидал получить ТС. Но в вопросе нигде не указано, что значения fav_user_creator и fav_user_with можно как то смешивать при сортировке. И если можно, то не указано как именно

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, подзапросы разные бывают. Если сингулярный, то легко - также как в секции WHERE